# How to allow more then one user to access facebook api

Tags: java, android, facebook, api

Hi i've integrated **Facebook** application with my application.

This is only working for the user-account who is registered with the application.

I am not able to find the **authorizing** screen just after **login** for users other then the registered user.

How can i achieve this ?

I am using following permission array:-

```
FACEBOOK_PERMISSION = {"offline_access", "publish_stream",
        "user_photos", "publish_checkins", "photo_upload" };
```

Am i missing something please help me.

Comment: Is your app in sandbox mode? Is the **registered user** you are talking about is the one who created the app?

Comment: yes it is in sandbox mode and i am talking about the user who created the app.

Comment: Anvesh Saxena@ Can you please tell me solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are facing is directly related to the fact that your application is in the **sandbox mode**. In this mode only the developers, testers and other people registered in the app settings are able to access the application. To allow the general public to use your application, you will have to **disable the sandbox mode** and then everyone can use it.